# What is the mMac equivalent to groupmod

Tags: linux, macos, user-accounts

I can find 1000s of answers for groupadd and usermod, but what I want to do is change the name of a group

```
groupmod -n biostat 1387956079
```

How do I do this in Mac OS/X 10.9?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at dseditgroup(8), it should do what you need.

To change the name of a group with name oldname to biostat, you would use something like:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -n .  -r biostat -T group oldname
```